# How to managing a large number of clients in the socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, serversocket

In examples, I saw of socket programming projects (most of which were chat projects), they often saved all the clients in one array, and when a message was received from a client, in addition to saving it in the database, to all clients also was sent.

The question that comes to my mind is: How can this message received from the client  and saved in the database and send to clients when number of clients is very large? (I mean, the number of customers is so large that a single server can't meet their demand alone, and several servers are needed to connect sockets).

In this case, not all clients can be managed through the array. So how do you transfer a message that is now stored on another server (by another customer) to a customer on this server? (Speed ​​is important).

Is there a way to quickly become aware of database changes and provide them to the customer? (For example, Telegram.)

I'm looking for a perspective, not a code.

Comment: @ashwinvinod What title do you recommend for searching?

Comment: I would recommend when posting questions to use spaces and break up the sentences in sections. Also a read through may help you catch a bunch of grammer issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your database as your messaging center.  Have other servers watch for changes in the database either by subscription or by pulling on a time interval.  Obviously subscription would be fastest possible.

When a message is inserted, each server picks this up and sends to their list of clients.  This should be quite fast for broadcasting messages.

Comment: But doesn't servicing the database by servers reduce performance? When should servers be required to listen? Can you explain a little more? But doesn't servicing the database by servers reduce performance? When should servers be required to listen? Can you explain a little more?For example, do servers constantly check the database in an infinite loop?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Most databases have something similar to an 'Operations' log or 'oplog'.  This oplog will contain any changes to the database.  Most databases allow access to this and you can watch for a specific table/collection to have a new entry/document inserted via a subscription.  This would require your servers to be connected via websocket.  If you connect via http, then your best bet is to poll at a specified interval.  If you have a decent sized server running your database, it should be able to handle several queries each second or 5 seconds, however you deem necessary. Query smart for new ones

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading about the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) and then continue with the [C10M problem](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a project at Github that is similar to my question?